# Finding exponent $e$ in RSA given modulus and a plaintext/ciphertext pair

Tags: rsa, modular-arithmetic

Assuming
$$c = m ^ e \bmod n$$
and given the values of $c$, $m$ and $n$ (32 bit integers),

How would one find the exponent $e$ (also 32 bit integer) ?

Comment: The value of e, depending on the protocol you are using is more or less standard, with most common being, 2^16+1,3 and sometimes 7. For more details you may check PKCS #1.

Comment: Using RSA with a 32 bit modulus is a quite huge mistake in the setup already. Or actually, this isn't RSA any more, if you ignore the assumption that $p$ and $q$ are large primes. And "large" means, that $n$ has to be 1024 bits at the very least, and some even consider that too small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this question we are given $c$, $m$ and $n$ (32 bit integers with $0\le c<n$), and asked to find the exponent $e$ (also 32 bit integer, odd and at least $3$) matching the equation of textbook RSA encryption: $c=m^e\bmod n$.

That's impossible with certainty unless $n$ is prime (which would not be RSA) and exactly 32-bit, because then the solution is never unique; either there is no solution, or several values of $e$ are possible. For some parameters (like $m=c=0$, $m=c=1$, or $m=c=n-1$), all odd values of $e$ work. If there's a solution, there is one below $\lambda(n)$ with $\lambda(n)=\operatorname{lcm}(p-1,q-1)$ when $n=p\;q$ with $p$ and $q$ distinct primes; that's the [Carmichael function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function), and is less than $2^{31}$ in an RSA context when $n$ is an at-most-32-bit composite; and then $e+\lambda(n)$ will be at-most-32-bit and also be a solution.

What we can find is the lowest odd value of $e$ at least $3$ such that $c=m^e\bmod n$ holds. The simplest method is perfectly adequate in the context if we can use a computer:

- $a\gets m\cdot m\bmod n$
- $e\gets 1$
- $b\gets m$; it holds that $b=m^e\bmod n$
- repeat until $e=2^{32}-1$

  - $e\gets e+2$
  - $b\gets a\cdot b\bmod n$; again it holds that $b=m^e\bmod n$
  - if $c=b$

    - output "One solution is" $e$ and stop
- output "There is no solution" and stop.

This requires $(e+1)/2$ modular multiplications if a solution is found, and  in any case no more than $2^{31}$.

---

There are at least two independent speedups which would allows to reduce the work, or/and tackle larger parameters:

- There are better algorithms than exhaustive search to solve a [Discrete Logarithm Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm), including [baby-step/giant-step](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baby-step_giant-step) which reduces the work to $O(\sqrt n)$ modular multiplications; and [Pollard's rho](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_rho_algorithm_for_logarithms) which is simpler and tends to be faster on average (but won't necessarily give the lowest $e$).
- If we can factor $n$ (and it is [square- free](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-free_integer) as customary in RSA), then we can solve the equation $c\equiv m^{e_p}\pmod p$ for each prime factor $p$ of $n$, then combine the results into $e$ using the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem), noting that if $e\equiv e_p\pmod{p-1}$ for each prime $p$ dividing $n$, this $e$ will be a solution (there might be cases where we miss the lowest $e$).

Comment: In the case of a 32 bit $n$, the last alternative would  probably be the fastest overall: Factorization should be quite fast, and then solving the dlog for both 16 bit primes independently and combining the results.

Comment: Thank you. The last alternative is helpful. I have tagged the question with "rsa" only because of the shape of the equation and have caused a confusion. The n here is not the standard p * q and can be factored.

Comment: @Mindaugas: I infered that $e$ is odd because of the question's original title _"Finding exponent (e) in RSA"_. If that's not RSA, then nothing tells us that $e$ is even; the algorithm needs a minor tweak, and is even simpler (we have no use of $a$). The two speedups still work.